# error while deploying grails app under tomcat 5.5

Tags: grails

I have a grails app developed under version 1.3.7It works very well when I run using grails command "grails run-app" .

I created the war file using the grails command "grails war" and deployed it into the tomcat 5.5 version running on my local machine. The app doesnt show up on the url..

When I checked the log files, there were few INFO statements followed by an error saying "Error listenerstart". Below is the text from the log file.

```
Sep 20, 2011 1:57:44 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: Loaded APR based Apache Tomcat Native library 1.1.20.
Sep 20, 2011 1:57:44 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: APR capabilities: IPv6 [true], sendfile [true], accept filters [false], random [true].
Sep 20, 2011 1:57:44 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol init
INFO: Initializing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
Sep 20, 2011 1:57:44 PM org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpAprProtocol init
INFO: Initializing Coyote AJP/1.3 on ajp-8009
Sep 20, 2011 1:57:44 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 484 ms
Sep 20, 2011 1:57:44 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService start
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Sep 20, 2011 1:57:44 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine start
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/5.5.33
Sep 20, 2011 1:57:44 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost start
INFO: XML validation disabled
Sep 20, 2011 1:57:45 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deploying web application archive sample-0.2.war
Sep 20, 2011 1:57:49 PM org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext
INFO: Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
Sep 20, 2011 1:57:49 PM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Tue Sep 20 13:57:49 MDT 2011]; root of context hierarchy
Sep 20, 2011 1:57:49 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]
Sep 20, 2011 1:57:49 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory preInstantiateSingletons
INFO: Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@1cf662f: defining beans [grailsApplication,pluginManager,grailsConfigurator,grailsResourceLoader,grailsResourceHolder,characterEncodingFilter]; root of factory hierarchy
Sep 20, 2011 1:57:49 PM org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.GrailsApplicationFactoryBean afterPropertiesSet
INFO: Loading Grails application with information from descriptor.
Sep 20, 2011 1:57:49 PM org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.GrailsApplicationFactoryBean afterPropertiesSet
INFO: No reloading, using standard classloader.
Sep 20, 2011 1:57:50 PM org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.DefaultGrailsPluginManager findUserPlugins
INFO: Attempting to load [0] user defined plugins
Sep 20, 2011 1:57:50 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: Hibernate 3.3.1.GA
Sep 20, 2011 1:57:50 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: hibernate.properties not found
Sep 20, 2011 1:57:50 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
INFO: Bytecode provider name : javassist
Sep 20, 2011 1:57:50 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: using JDK 1.4 java.sql.Timestamp handling
Sep 20, 2011 1:57:50 PM org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.DefaultGrailsPluginManager registerPlugin
INFO: Grails plug-in [logging] with version [1.3.7] loaded successfully
Sep 20, 2011 1:57:50 PM org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.DefaultGrailsPluginManager registerPlugin
INFO: Grails plug-in [i18n] with version [1.3.7] loaded successfully
Sep 20, 2011 1:57:50 PM org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.DefaultGrailsPluginManager registerPlugin
INFO: Grails plug-in [core] with version [1.3.7] loaded successfully
Sep 20, 2011 1:57:50 PM org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.DefaultGrailsPluginManager registerPlugin
INFO: Grails plug-in [filters] with version [1.3.7] loaded successfully
Sep 20, 2011 1:57:50 PM org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.DefaultGrailsPluginManager registerPlugin
INFO: Grails plug-in [servlets] with version [1.3.7] loaded successfully
Sep 20, 2011 1:57:50 PM org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.DefaultGrailsPluginManager registerPlugin
INFO: Grails plug-in [release] with version [1.0.0.M1] loaded successfully
Sep 20, 2011 1:57:50 PM org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.DefaultGrailsPluginManager registerPlugin
INFO: Grails plug-in [svn] with version [1.0.0.M1] loaded successfully
Sep 20, 2011 1:57:50 PM org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.DefaultGrailsPluginManager registerPlugin
INFO: Grails plug-in [dataSource] with version [1.3.7] loaded successfully
Sep 20, 2011 1:57:50 PM org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.DefaultGrailsPluginManager registerPlugin
INFO: Grails plug-in [groovyPages] with version [1.3.7] loaded successfully
Sep 20, 2011 1:57:50 PM org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.DefaultGrailsPluginManager registerPlugin
INFO: Grails plug-in [codecs] with version [1.3.7] loaded successfully
Sep 20, 2011 1:57:50 PM org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.DefaultGrailsPluginManager registerPlugin
INFO: Grails plug-in [urlMappings] with version [1.3.7] loaded successfully
Sep 20, 2011 1:57:50 PM org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.DefaultGrailsPluginManager registerPlugin
INFO: Grails plug-in [controllers] with version [1.3.7] loaded successfully
Sep 20, 2011 1:57:50 PM org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.DefaultGrailsPluginManager registerPlugin
INFO: Grails plug-in [scaffolding] with version [1.3.7] loaded successfully
Sep 20, 2011 1:57:50 PM org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.DefaultGrailsPluginManager registerPlugin
INFO: Grails plug-in [mimeTypes] with version [1.3.7] loaded successfully
Sep 20, 2011 1:57:50 PM org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.DefaultGrailsPluginManager registerPlugin
INFO: Grails plug-in [domainClass] with version [1.3.7] loaded successfully
Sep 20, 2011 1:57:50 PM org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.DefaultGrailsPluginManager registerPlugin
INFO: Grails plug-in [converters] with version [1.3.7] loaded successfully
Sep 20, 2011 1:57:50 PM org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.DefaultGrailsPluginManager registerPlugin
INFO: Grails plug-in [hibernate] with version [1.3.7] loaded successfully
Sep 20, 2011 1:57:50 PM org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.DefaultGrailsPluginManager registerPlugin
INFO: Grails plug-in [services] with version [1.3.7] loaded successfully
Sep 20, 2011 1:57:50 PM org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.DefaultGrailsPluginManager registerPlugin
INFO: Grails plug-in [validation] with version [1.3.7] loaded successfully
Sep 20, 2011 1:57:51 PM org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.TagLibArtefactHandler initialize
INFO: There are conflicting tags: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.web.taglib.FormTagLib.g:out vs. org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.web.taglib.RenderTagLib.g:out. The former will take precedence.
Sep 20, 2011 1:57:51 PM org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.TagLibArtefactHandler initialize
INFO: There are conflicting tags: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.web.taglib.FormTagLib.g:out vs. org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.web.taglib.RenderTagLib.g:out. The former will take precedence.
Sep 20, 2011 1:57:51 PM org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.TagLibArtefactHandler initialize
INFO: There are conflicting tags: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.web.taglib.FormTagLib.g:out vs. org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.web.taglib.RenderTagLib.g:out. The former will take precedence.
Sep 20, 2011 1:57:51 PM org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.TagLibArtefactHandler initialize
INFO: There are conflicting tags: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.web.taglib.FormTagLib.g:out vs. org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.web.taglib.RenderTagLib.g:out. The former will take precedence.
Sep 20, 2011 1:57:54 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
Sep 20, 2011 1:57:54 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Context [/sample-0.2] startup failed due to previous errors
Sep 20, 2011 1:57:55 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol start
INFO: Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
Sep 20, 2011 1:57:55 PM org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpAprProtocol start
INFO: Starting Coyote AJP/1.3 on ajp-8009
Sep 20, 2011 1:57:55 PM org.apache.catalina.storeconfig.StoreLoader load
INFO: Find registry server-registry.xml at classpath resource
Sep 20, 2011 1:57:55 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 10438 ms
Sep 20, 2011 1:58:09 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
Sep 20, 2011 1:58:09 PM org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpAprProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing Coyote AJP/1.3 on ajp-8009
Sep 20, 2011 1:58:10 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stop
INFO: Stopping service Catalina
Sep 20, 2011 1:58:10 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol destroy
INFO: Stopping Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
Sep 20, 2011 1:58:10 PM org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpAprProtocol destroy
INFO: Stopping Coyote AJP/1.3 on ajp-8009
```

I really appreciate your help here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the problem got resolved. In my case, I was using a wrong netcdf JAR file. There are two netcdf-java jar files. One is netcdfAll-{version}.jar and netcdf-{version}.jar. Initially, I was using the netcdfAll-{version}.jar, when I replaced it with netcdf-{version}.jar, the error got resolved. The reason I am thinking is the first specified netcdfAll jar file has logging dependencies that would have caused the error. This is just my opinion, I have no log error evidence to prove that so. Replacing the jar file just worked fine in my case.

I had  been solving this issue for the past 4 days and I did an extensive search on Google for this error and read through various forums and Q&A sites to see how people had resolved their error. In most of the cases, the error was due to the JAR files present in the {your-app}/WEB-INF/lib/ directory. It may be missing some required jar files or presence of duplicate JAR files.Something to do with the JAR files. So, just a little tip, we you face an error like this on tomcat be sure to double check your lib directory to see you have the correct set of JAR files. I also tried several logging implementations, to see the system log the cause of the error, in my case I couldn't find any stacktrace being produced.

Anyways, the error is resolved and thanks to "Hans Westerbeek" for helping on this.

Answer (score 0):

My colleague Jelmer has written a blog posting about [exactly this subject](http://blog.jteam.nl/2011/03/18/debugging-the-dreaded-severe-error-listenerstart-and-severe-error-filterstart-tomcat-error-messages/)

Read it and you will find out how to get log output for the ERROR:ListenerStart. That will help you solve your problem.

Comment: Hi,I followed the blog but I dint get any stacktrace displayed. Will thate be displayed on the console or written to a separate file. If so, where can I find the file?